# Does casting Silent Image break Invisibility?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

My character is invisible.

He casts Silent Image to create a giant scroll a few hundred feet in the air with a mean old message written in the sky with a large font.

Does reading the message contained in the Silent Image (interacting with the illusion to give a saving throw) break the invisibility spell?

Answer (score 5):

No, you are not directly targeting a foe.

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility/

The spell ends if the subject attacks any creature. For purposes of this spell, an attack includes any spell targeting a foe or whose area or effect includes a foe. Exactly who is a foe depends on the invisible character’s perceptions. Actions directed at unattended objects do not break the spell. Causing harm indirectly is not an attack. *Thus, an invisible being can open doors, talk, eat, climb stairs, **summon monsters and have them attack**, cut the ropes holding a rope bridge while enemies are on the bridge, remotely trigger traps, open a portcullis to release attack dogs, and so forth.* If the subject attacks directly, however, it immediately becomes visible along with all its gear. Spells such as bless that specifically affect allies but not foes are not attacks for this purpose, even when they include foes in their area.

I'd think that casting the silent image in the sky would be in line with the summoning.

Comment: Maybe I was thinking that people who interact with the illusion get a saving throw. Does reading the message count as interacting with it? What if they try and shoot an arrow through it.

Comment: @FrancisJohn They would not get a saving throw, silent image is a Lv1 spell, so it is quite a common spell. Almost anyone who saw it just hovering there would be able to deduce that it was an illusion spell. reading it would count as interacting if it, although if the distance made a difference or not is up to your GM. To read something one needs to examine it to comprehend the words, so silent image used like that gives them a save chance. Simply seeing it doesn't count the same as examining it.

Comment: So, a better answer is: As long as the Silent image's area does not include the enemy. If it does, the primary clause triggers.